# Can I use Oracle JDeveloper 12C with 4GB ram?

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

When am working with 4GB RAM, the JDK is consuming all the RAM and the Processing speed is very less and unable to proceed with the work. Even for saving a simple JSF page, it's consuming 5-8 minutes.

So is it mandatory to use a RAM >4GB or is there any optimising technique so that I can continue with 4GB RAM and obtain better performance?

Comment: I'm assuming that JDeveloper is started via a shortcut which executes the java runtime engine. If this is correct, try specifying the command line argument `-Xmx2048m` on the java command line - this will limit the heap size to 2G max. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4GB should be enough - the slow performance you are seeing doesn't seem to be related to memory but rather something else - try disabling the antivirus on your machine.
Some anti viruses scan JAR files as they are uploaded slowing down Java software such as JDeveloper.

Comment: thanks Shay
apologies for marking the answer very late.

Answer (score 2):

4 GB is enough use,you should improve memory management.

java parameters like

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:+UseParallelGC
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

for JDeveloper and for tomcat . You should find some JDeveloper config file and change memory management.